# Is it possible to retrofit an ABS?

Tags: brakes, suzuki, abs, aftermarket-upgrade, retrofit

Is it possible to (and safely) retrofit an ABS system on a car/van?

The vehicle in question is a [Suzuki APV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suzuki_APV). Some overseas models come with ABS as standard but not where I live.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, just get all the parts from an APV that has ABS. You will likely need:

- all 4 wheel hubs because the sensor is built in
- the wiring
- the ABS controller

You may need to swap your ECU for one that knows about ABS controllers.

Comment: They'd most likely need everything which attaches to this stuff as well, such as wiring, brake lines (hydraulic), and whatever else.